# Find the area of the shaded region?

Tags: calculus, graphing-functions, area

So the question is listed below as a picture, I realize I have to subtract the min and max after inputting them into the equation. So far I think it would be integral x going from 0 and going to 11/2? 
[image]

Comment: You have the right limits, but they are limits on $y$, not on $x$.

Comment: You want area to be positive, so you should integrate the difference $x_{blue} - x_{red}$ (both functions of $y$) over the interval $[0, \frac{11}{2}]$.

Comment: Hey, I am still not sure of how to get the answer :( is it 13.75?

Answer (score 3):

You can calculate the area to the right of both curves and left of the $y$-axis between $y=0$ and $y=\frac {11}2$ by integrating the given functions. Then, you can substract the results to get the area.

Also, just mirroring the image in $x=y$ or rotating it by a quarter turn may help.

**EDIT**
One integral (the blue one) should be $\frac{121}{12}$ and the red one should be $\frac{1573}{24}$. The difference is the area. (I'm assuming we're only talking about positive areas here.)

Comment: I got -13.75 + 13.75 (after inputting 11/2 for y in both equations) I am so confused

Comment: Yes, I get the difference to be -1331/24, not sure if it's correct, I am so upset with myself, I am having too much difficulty with this question!

Comment: if you omit the minus-sign, it is correct. Because you are calculating an area, it has to be positive. (For integrals in general, that isn't true, but because of the interpretation, the answer is positive here.)

Answer (score 2):

If you look sideways you can do $\int \Delta x\ dy$ to get the area.  The advantage is that you always take the difference of the two curves.  If you integrate $\int \Delta y \  dx$ you have regions where you need to integrate between branches of the same curve.  Either way will work, but having only one type of integral simplifies things.  $$\begin {align}\int_0^{11/2} 3y-y^2-(y^2-8y) dy&=\int_0^{11/2} 11y-2y^2 dy\\
&=\left.\frac {11y^2}2-\frac 23y^3\right|_0^{11/2}\\ &=\frac 13\left(\frac{11}2\right)^3\\&=\frac{1331}{24}\end {align}$$

Comment: Thank you so, so, so much. I finally comprehend :)